# cannot place view programatically using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout that has an image view which is like an archery target. On touch event I'm trying to place another image (a bullet) where user pressed on the target. However, I can only adjust the top alignment of the image which is correct, but I cannot adjust the view horizonaly at all. It always ends up adjusted to the left. What am doing wrong ? The coordinates are working 100% ok, I even tried hardcoding the values but no luck.

```
 target.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
            imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
            float[] touchPoint = new float[]{event.getX(), event.getY()};
            inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
            int x = (int) touchPoint[0];
            int y = (int) touchPoint[1];

            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams vp =
                new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.bullet);
            view.setImageBitmap(bm);
            layout.addView(view, 7, vp);
            set.clone(layout);
            set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
            target.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, (int) y - 60);
            set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, target.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, (int) x);
            set.applyTo(layout);

        }
    });
```

Comment: See updated answer with solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into this issue:  [62154545
ConstraintSet connect ignores right and left margins](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62154545).

> When adding a TextView using ConstraintSet#connect to an empty ConstraintLayout defined in XML, left and right margins are ignored (are zero) while top and bottom margins are honored. The TextView height and width are both set to "MATCH_CONSTRAINT". See the following code and screen shot. This works fine when everything is set in XML.

---

Just took another look at this. Use `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` instead of `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT`. I just tried it and it works OK. I can't say why left and right don't work.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll try it out. I ended up using relative layout to solve this urgently.